# titlesec Indented Block Format

Tags: formatting, sectioning, titlesec

I am trying to achieve the following formatting using the `titlesec` package.

[image: desired format]

`\titleformat{}[wrap]{}{}{}{}` works well to achieve the "5.2." and the wrapping of its child text.

What is the best way to achieve the next layer of formatting, for the alphabetically ordered text? That is, instead of wrapping, I would like the child text (the latin script) to be formatted as an aligned (indented) block. Note additionally, I would like to be able to provide *un*-indented 'answer contents' for each alphabetically ordered layer.

I am wondering if there is an 'industry-standard' solution to this particular formatting schema in LaTeX!

Here is a failed implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec} % section headings
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\titleformat{\section}[wrap]{\normalfont}{}{}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\normalfont}{}{}{} % block --> ??

\begin{document}

\section{5.2.}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget vestibulum dolor. Donec commodo nec lorem quis faucibus. Sed ligula metus, aliquet vel turpis vel, maximus dictum tellus. Ut ullamcorper neque nisi, dictum rutrum turpis tincidunt non. Curabitur sagittis, nulla nec aliquam tristique, diam turpis venenatis quam, quis suscipit tellus mi et sapien. Quisque diam justo, pharetra rhoncus risus eget, aliquet hendrerit nisi. 


\subsection{a.}

{Aliquam a mauris lacus. Nulla at tempus leo. Nullam convallis odio turpis, a mattis est venenatis non. Cras ut viverra nisl. Vestibulum mollis sapien justo, eget fermentum tellus gravida in. Proin sed risus nec ipsum rutrum rutrum ac quis eros.}


Answer content (a)

\end{document}
```

Which renders as:

[image: render]

Clearly it is lacking both the desired formatting for (a), as well as the ability to have un-indented answer content.

**NOTE**: This was answered in a [better question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/704952/309793), considering all answers to this one pointed me towards a different solution entirely (particularly, I ended up using `enumitem` rather than `titlesec`, dropping the \subsection formatting I was using for the a., b., c., etc).

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  This question would benefit from the addition of a small compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  Without knowing the document class and other relevant packages that you are using, any attempt at an answer would be largely a guess.

Comment: thanks, updated with example

Comment: How is TeX to know when subsection a has "ended" and "Answer content (a)" has started? The latter has a different indent. I don't think you really want to use subsection for the alphabetic items. You probably want some sort of environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more readily achievable using lists.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[itemindent=1em,labelwidth=3em,align=left]
  \item[5.2.]
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget vestibulum dolor. 
  Donec commodo nec lorem quis faucibus. Sed ligula metus, aliquet vel turpis vel, maximus dictum 
  tellus. Ut ullamcorper neque nisi, dictum rutrum turpis tincidunt non. Curabitur sagittis, 
  nulla nec aliquam tristique, diam turpis venenatis quam, quis suscipit tellus mi et sapien. 
  Quisque diam justo, pharetra rhoncus risus eget, aliquet hendrerit nisi. 

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item[a.]
    Aliquam a mauris lacus. Nulla at tempus leo. Nullam convallis odio turpis, a mattis est 
    venenatis non. Cras ut viverra nisl. Vestibulum mollis sapien justo, eget fermentum tellus 
    gravida in. Proin sed risus nec ipsum rutrum rutrum ac quis eros.
  \end{enumerate}

  Answer content (a)

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item[b.]
    Aliquam a mauris lacus. Nulla at tempus leo. Nullam convallis odio turpis, a mattis est 
    venenatis non. Cras ut viverra nisl. Vestibulum mollis sapien justo, eget fermentum tellus 
    gravida in. Proin sed risus nec ipsum rutrum rutrum ac quis eros.
  \end{enumerate}

  Answer content (b)
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

With a more clear context, some automation can be incorporated (using `series` to define a specific list style/format, for example).

Comment: only difference in my solution was i kept the \section formatting for 5.2., and specified my `enumerate` environment with `[label={\alph*.}]` while using `[resume*]` to keep it consistent across environments.